# Method to execute when a class instance falls out of scope?

Tags: java, c++, migration

I have a C++ class used to trace the entry and exit from called routines.

```
class myTrace{
    std::string  m_strName;
    myTrace( std::string strName ){
        m_strName = strName;
        _tprintf( _T("\n%s entering"), m_strName );
    };
    ~myTrace(){
        _tprintf(_T("\n%s exiting"), m_strName );
    };
};
```

It's simple to use, you instantiate it as the 1st thing done in a routine using a stack mechanism.  When the routine is called it prints out and entry message.  When the routine exits, it prints out an exit message.

I'm trying to migrate this to java, but all of the reading i've done about the absence of destructors has me confused about whether or not there's any way this be done in java?

-bob lambert-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java, executing a method when object's scope ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117783/java-executing-a-method-when-objects-scope-ends)

Answer (score 0):

just in theory, you can override method finalize, so

```
public class MyClass {
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("exiting");
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

this will be called by garbage collector when it determines that there are no more references to the object

so when you do

```
public static void myMethod()
{
MyClass a = new MyClass();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod();
        System.gc();
}
```

as output you will get

> exiting

if i remember in C++ destructors are for release memory when object will be destroyed, in java we dont have to worry about this, GC is doing this for us. So in most cases you shouldn't really needed destructos

Comment: I understood that from prior readings on this topic.  The problem is that this is a routine entry/exit trace mechanism, which bypasses the problems of unexpected or multiple exit points from the routine which is being traced.  The 'exit' portion of the trace has to happen when the routine exits; not when the GC decides there are no more references.  It may be that the class construction/destruction behavior that i'm taking advantage of in C++ has no analog in java, and an alternate solution will need to be implemented.

Comment: if you have issue related to unexpected exit points, you can use finally block, which perform action after you exit block, is that is closer to this what you are looking for?