# What is the best way to emulate try-with-resources in Java 6?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

It turns out that almost nobody closes resources in Java correctly. Programmers either do not use `try-finally` block at all, or just put `resource.close()` in `finally` which is also incorrect (because `Throwable` from `close()` can shadow `Throwable` from try block). Sometimes they put something like `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` with is only correct for `InputStream`, but not for `OutputStream`. `try-with-resources` solves all of these problems but there are still huge number of projects written in Java 6.

What is the best way to emulate `try-with-resources` in Java 6? Now I use [Guava Closer](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ClosingResourcesExplained), which is better than nothing but still much uglier than `try-with-resources`. Also, there is a pattern called a loan-pattern, but the absence of lambdas in Java makes this pattern very cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Comment: Use the Java 7 compiler?

Comment: Guava Closer seems to be as elegant as it can get with Java 6.

Comment: I can't use the Java 7 compiler

Comment: FYI `IOUtils.closeQuietly` in newer versions of `commons-io` is defined for `Closable` interface. So you can close what you want with it (not just streams). http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.Closeable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a good replacement for `try-with-resources`. It uses [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) library with annotation processing:

```
 @Cleanup InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
 @Cleanup OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
 byte[] b = new byte[10000];
 while (true) {
   int r = in.read(b);
   if (r == -1) break;
   out.write(b, 0, r);
 }
```

However, it doesn't handle exception correctly. This bug is more than 1 year old and still is not closed: https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=384

Answer (score 0):

Though anonymous class is quite verbose, it's still acceptable in java land

```
    new TryWithResource<InputStream>(){
        protected InputStream init() throws Exception {
            return new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
        }
        protected void use(InputStream input) throws Exception{
            input.read();
        }
    };

----

abstract class TryWithResource<R>
{
    abstract protected R init() throws Exception;
    abstract protected void use(R resource) throws Exception;

    // caution: invoking virtual methods in constructor!
    TryWithResource() throws Exception
    {
        // ... code before
        R r = init();
        use(r);
        // ... code after
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the close happening?

Comment: That's wrong, if `use` throws an exception then the stream will not be closed. You would need to wrap a try/finally block anyway, thus you're solution is just more code for the same job.

Comment: `code before/after` involves try/finally. I thought that is self evident for anyone interested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem with `IOUtils.closeQuietly` is that it ignores exceptions on OutputStreams, then you can either simply call `close()` on them, or create your own utility class which automatically treats the two differently, like this:

```
public static void close(Closeable resource)
{
    try
    {
        resource.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //swallow exception
    }
}

public static void close(OutputStream o)
{
    //throw any exceptions
    o.close();
}
```

The correct overloaded method will be selected at compile time in all common situations, although if you're passing `OutputStream`s around as `Closeable`s then you'll have to change this to do a dynamic `instanceof` check to make sure `OutputStream`s always throw exceptions.

Comment: The code required to properly deal with cleanup exceptions is just plain nasty without try-with-resources, since such exceptions should propagate if the `try` block succeeds, but be suppressed if it fails.